# Panel doesn't resize it's contents in Design Mode

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a UserControl I'm making which works fine when in execution, but doesn't resize in design mode.

The UserControl has an image background that is resized to fill when the Control resizes.  Drawing that works fine. 
To deal with the fact that the image stretches, I have a panel that holds the content. 
During initialization, I store a Left, Top, Width and Height Ratio.  ( pnl.Left / this.Width , etc..)

During Resize event, I then move and resize the content panel based on the new size of the control and the ratios I have saved.  The _contentDimensions is a structure that stores the Ratios.  ReDimension is a method that takes a control and moves/resizes it based on the ratio to new size.

```
private void Control_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        _contentDimensions.ReDimension(this.ClientSize, pnlContent);
    }
    catch { }
    finally
    {
        this.ResumeLayout(true);
    }
}
```

While this works during runtime, If I resize the UserControl during DesignTime, The content Panel doesn't Resize.

Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot offer an answer I'm afraid but I've seen this too.

Comment: Why do you care to have it resize during design time? Runtime is where it counts.

Comment: @banging  Mostly its for future me.  When I have to go back in and add some screen real estate, it would be nice If I didn't have to go and move everything.  But more importantly, I like to understand how things work and it seems to me that It should resize, but it doesn't, and I got stumped.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely calling `Control_Resize` from the wrong location. Put your re-size logic in a overload of `OnSizeChanged`

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        MessageBox.Show("Size Changed!");
    }
}
```

When I add that control to my test form and attempt to re-size it I get this in visual studio:

[image]

---

As a extra side tidbit, calling [this.DesignMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx) from your user control can tell you if you are being rendered in visual studio. This can be useful if you have some slow operations that happen on load (like starting a query to a database on a background thread) that you don't need to do if you are in design mode.

Comment: That didn't work for me, Im wondering if this is because I'm in 2005, maybe its a limitation of the older IDE.

Comment: Can you edit your original question and add in the code that calls `Control_Resize`? Also Look at the debugging trick I talk about in the comment of Steve's answer. If you attach a 2nd copy of visual stuido to the first copy and put in a breakpoint in the constructor does it get called? if so you can step through and find out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio Designer does not fire events for your UserControls.  It works by constructing an instance of your object and parsing the InitializeComponent() method.

One possible workaround is to use the Anchor/Dock properties of a control to automatically size your child image and panel.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx.

Comment: Actually it does not "parse" per say but run your actual code. You can open a 2nd copy of visual studio, attach it to the first copy and put a breakpoint in your form code and watch it get hit. In fact you can check `this.DesignMode` of your form and it will return true whenever your form is being rendered by VS.